How to clone or download locally a Replit repo from bash?
How can I clone or download locally a Replit repository from bash or CLI?
I tried:
git clone https://replit.com/@USER/REPO
Also I tried:
wget https://replit.com/@USER/REPO.zip
But for this second option need to be logged in and fork the repo first.
I need to do all from bash cli.
Is this possible?

I think you'll need to link it to a github account and clone from there: https://docs.replit.com/category/using-git-on-replit
